# Custom Numeric Keyboard Layout for React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there any package or resource help for Custom Numeric Keyboard Layout for React Native like this image ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think that you can use [beefe](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-keyboard) for styling the keyboard.

**Images:**

[image][image]

**Example code:**

```
"use strict";

import React, { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Keyboard from "react-native-keyboard";

let model = {
  _keys: [],

  _listeners: [],

  addKey(key) {
    this._keys.push(key);
    this._notify();
  },

  delKey() {
    this._keys.pop();
    this._notify();
  },

  clearAll() {
    this._keys = [];
    this._notify();
  },

  getKeys() {
    return this._keys;
  },

  onChange(listener) {
    if (typeof listener === "function") {
      this._listeners.push(listener);
    }
  },

  _notify() {
    this._listeners.forEach(listner => {
      listner(this);
    });
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    model.onChange(model => {
      this.setState({ text: model.getKeys().join("") });
    });
  }

  _handleClear() {
    model.clearAll();
  }

  _handleDelete() {
    model.delKey();
  }

  _handleKeyPress(key) {
    model.addKey(key);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.text}</Text>
        </View>
        <Keyboard
          keyboardType="decimal-pad"
          onClear={this._handleClear.bind(this)}
          onDelete={this._handleDelete.bind(this)}
          onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyboardType={'phone-pad'}` in TextInput as shown below.

```
<TextInput 
    style={styles.phoneNumberInput} 
    maxLength={10} 
    keyboardType={'phone-pad'} 
    onChangeText={
        (number) => this.onChange(number)
    } 
    value={this.state.myNumber} 
    returnKeyType='go'
    onSubmitEditing={
        () => this.xyz()
    } 
/>
```

[Looks Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMKzq.png)

Ref: [TextInput Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)

Answer (score 0):

We've done a similar custom keypad using https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-custom-keyboard

It is not 100% straightforward, but we've made it work. It allows you to bind this keyboard to your input so that it functions like a native keyboard.